# JPA add seconds to date in query

Tags: mysql, sql, date, addition, jpql

I have a table called "Task" which has, among others, two columns:

- Date_due: a TIMESTAMP date
- Wait_in_seconds: a number (INT) of seconds

I want to add the Wait_in_seconds value to the date in the query and compare it to the current date.

The query below doesn't have the right syntax, but it indicates what I want:

```
SELECT t
FROM Task t
WHERE (Date_due + Wait_in_seconds) < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

**Edit:** KIMI explains that this is not possible with JPQL.

**Edit 2:** This native MySQL query does the trick:

```
SELECT *, DATE_ADD(task.date_due, INTERVAL task.wait_seconds SECOND) AS dueDate
FROM task                   
HAVING dueDate < NOW()
ORDER BY dueDate ASC
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Standard JPQL does not support such operations on dates. You will have to either use a native query or do the computation on the Java side, for example with [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) which is a reference implementation of [JSR-310](http://java.net/projects/jsr-310/).

Comment: Thx. I prefer a native sql query over computation in java code. I will update the OT.

Comment: "How would it be done with a native SQL query?" First of all, it depends on the database. Which database are you using?